# Issue pushing 60Hz @ 4k

Tags: display, hdmi, 4k-monitor, usb-c

I have a Lenovo Yoga 900 running Ubuntu 16.04 and kernel version 4.7.0. I'm using a USB-C -> HDMI 2.0 adapter to push my Seiki SE42UM TV.

I can get full 4k@60Hz in Windows, but in Ubuntu I can't get more than 30Hz (even though xrandr detects that the 60Hz option exists). If I run at 60, the screen just starts pulsing and looks like a strobe light. 30Hz works fine, but there is a big time lag which is super annoying.

Working at 1080p might be possible, but the text is very blurry (I think that might have something to do with the Seiki not having a built in scaler or something like that?)

After plugging in my AC adapter, I can get 60Hz with no problem.

Also, for some reason, my TV is showing this every 2 seconds without fail. I'm assuming it keeps getting reconnect signals or something?

[image: Connection display]

Anything I can do?